# How to restart android InputMethodService

Tags: android, keyboard

I am developing a soft keyboard for android. I want to restart the Input Method Service from settingsAcitivty. Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it now. I add this line in onStartInputView method.

```
setInputView(onCreateInputView());
```