# How to change the theme of a Custom Soft Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I have developed a custom keyboard specified for the letters used in Circassian. The problem is I cannot change the theme (apperance) of my keyboard in respect to the theme user selected. I've provided a UI to let users select a theme of their choice. After clicking the select theme method, InputMethodService stops and starts. But the keyboard stays the same.

I've created layout files for each theme I'd like to add and I'm using them to create KeyboardView instance on onCreateInputView method of InputMethodService. Below is the code for InputMethodService.

```
package net.dijitalbeyin.circassian_keyboard;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;

public class MyInputMethodService extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
    private KeyboardView keyboardView;
    private Keyboard qwertyKeyboard;
    private Keyboard symbolsKeyboard;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private boolean isJustStarted = true;
    private boolean isCaps = false;
    private boolean isAfterDot = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String selectedThemeName = sharedPreferences.getString("selectedThemeName", "Green");
        setKeyboardTheme(selectedThemeName);
        keyboardView.setKeyboard(qwertyKeyboard);
        keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        shiftKeyboard();
        return keyboardView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (inputConnection != null) {
            playSound(primaryCode);
            switch (primaryCode) {
                case Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE:
                    Keyboard currentKeyboard = keyboardView.getKeyboard();
                    if (currentKeyboard == qwertyKeyboard) {
                        currentKeyboard = symbolsKeyboard;
                    } else {
                        currentKeyboard = qwertyKeyboard;
                    }
                    keyboardView.setKeyboard(currentKeyboard);
                    break;
                case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                    CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                        inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                    } else {
                        inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                    isCaps = !isCaps;
                    qwertyKeyboard.setShifted(isCaps);
                    keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
                    break;
                case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                    inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                    break;
                default:
                    char code = (char) primaryCode;
                    if (Character.isLetter(code) && isCaps) {
                        code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                    }
                    inputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
                    if (isJustStarted) {
                        unshiftKeyboard();
                        isJustStarted = false;
                    }
                    if (isAfterDot) {
                        unshiftKeyboard();
                    }
                    if (code == 46) {
                        isAfterDot = true;
                        inputConnection.commitText(" ", 1);
                        shiftKeyboard();
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }

    private void playSound(int primaryCode) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case 32:
                audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            case 10:
                audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                break;
            default:
                audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    private void shiftKeyboard() {
        qwertyKeyboard.setShifted(true);
        keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
        isCaps = true;
    }

    private void unshiftKeyboard() {
        if (isCaps) {
            qwertyKeyboard.setShifted(false);
            keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
            isCaps = false;
        }
    }

    private void setKeyboardTheme(String selectedThemeName) {
        if (selectedThemeName.equals("Green")) {
            keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view_green_theme, null);
            qwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout_green_theme);
            symbolsKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols_green_theme);
        } else if (selectedThemeName.equals("Light")) {
            keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view_light_theme, null);
            qwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout_light_theme);
            symbolsKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols_light_theme);
        } else if (selectedThemeName.equals("Dark")) {
            keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view_dark_theme, null);
            qwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout_dark_theme);
            symbolsKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols_dark_theme);
        } else {
            keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view_green_theme, null);
            qwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout_green_theme);
            symbolsKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols_green_theme);
            Log.e("TAG", "Unknown theme selection: " + selectedThemeName);
        }
    }
}
```

ThemesActivity.java

```
package net.dijitalbeyin.circassian_keyboard;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class ThemesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ThemeAdapter.OnThemeListener {
    RecyclerView rw_themes;
    RecyclerView.Adapter themeAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    Theme[] themes = new Theme[3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_themes);

        rw_themes = findViewById(R.id.rw_themes);
        rw_themes.setHasFixedSize(true);

        int greenThemeImageResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("green_theme_preview", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        Theme greenTheme = new Theme("Green", greenThemeImageResourceId, true);
        int lightThemeImageResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("light_theme_preview", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        Theme lightTheme = new Theme("Light", lightThemeImageResourceId, false);
        int darkThemeImageResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("dark_theme_preview", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        Theme darkTheme = new Theme("Dark", darkThemeImageResourceId, false);
        themes[0] = greenTheme;
        themes[1] = lightTheme;
        themes[2] = darkTheme;

        themeAdapter = new ThemeAdapter(themes, this);
        rw_themes.setAdapter(themeAdapter);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        rw_themes.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThemeClick(int position) {
        Theme currentTheme = themes[position];
        if (!currentTheme.isActive()) {
            String curentThemeName = currentTheme.getThemeName();
            for (int i = 0; i < themes.length; i++) {
                if (themes[i].getThemeName().equals(curentThemeName)) {
                    themes[i].setActive(true);
                } else {
                    themes[i].setActive(false);
                }
            }
            sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("selectedThemeName", curentThemeName);
            editor.apply();
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyInputMethodService.class));
            startService(new Intent(this, MyInputMethodService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem applying the solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394866/6753606).
Overriding onStartInputMethod and calling

```
setInputView(onCreateInputView());
```